# LG oven -- power cord burning

Tags: electrical, oven

I purchased new LG oven **2 weeks ago** and smelled burning last night.
Come next morning, the oven doesn't turn on.
I checked on back of power cord section and opened the cover.
Inside, 3  of the wires (black, white, and red) were not secured at all, instead hanging from the bolt with no nut. The red wire was completely burned..

Is this normal???

[image]

Comment: I presume the cord is exiting out the bottom, correct?  Or is this oven hardwired?

Comment: Yes, exiting out the bottom from the oven hardwire. BUT NEVER CONNECTED WITH NUTS... just moving in & out when I opened the cover.

Answer (score 2):

I first want to comment that you are extremely fortunate to have discovered this before issue before it became a full scale fire in your dwelling.

Having no nuts on the studs to secure the lugs of the supply cord is a serious safety situation. Someone that installed the cord assembly screwed up royally.

If you received the LG oven with the cord already installed from the store or warehouse I would be recommending that you take it back and demand that they give you a replacement that is wired properly.

There is a possibility that the oven is OK and that acquiring a new cord assembly and installing it properly will be the cure to the problem. BUT... be aware that the red wire melted because the connection was high resistance and created a tremendous heat to melt the insulation like that. You will need to very carefully check the red wire from the oven internals that also connects to that stud. If it is in any way melted or discolored then you should seriously look at getting a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I'm pushing LG customer centre.. I DON'T RECOMMEND THIS LG.... LOL..

Comment: @MARTIN - It is possible that the LG customer centre is not the guilty party here. Many times the ovens are not pre-equipped with cordsets and these are installed by the dealer/store. (Sometimes it is dealt with by the purchaser or installer). Your first course of action has to be to go back to the folks you bought the thing from. It should be their responsibility to deal with the problem and if it falls to LG they should be dealing with that.